# compiling bootloader code, invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly, dos, bootloader, boot

i am compiling/assembling a boot loader code for ms dos as given below(line numbers are just for demonstration purpose)

```
1. START: CLI               ; Disable maskable Interrupts
2. XOR  AX,AX        ; Zero-out the Accumulator and set
3. MOV  SS,AX        ;  Stack Segment register to ZERO.
4. MOV  SP,0x7C00        ; Stack Pointer top now 0000:7C00
5. PUSH SS           ;|
6. POP  ES           ;|Makes sure Extra Segment = ZERO.
7. MOV  BX,0x0078      ; 0078h ---> BX
8. LABEL1: LDS  SI,SS:[BX]   ; SS is still zero...
                                 ; Load Far Pointer from [SS:0078]
                                 ; into DS:SI  (usually 0000:0522).
```

above code is giving following error in line number 8th:

```
error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

after some code of lines i am facing another error as given below:

```
9. MOV     CH,[MediaDescriptor]
10. MOV     DL,[DriveNumber]
11. MOV     BX,[7C49h]
12. MOV     AX,[LABEL7C4B]
13. JMP     FAR 0070:0000   ; Same as jumping to
                           ; 0000:0700 (start DOS).
; Boot Record found OS successfully... Jump to OS 
;initialization!
```

when i compile above given code then compiler is giving following error at line number 13th:

```
 error: mismatch in operand sizes
```

what is mistake, please help and guide.

Comment: you are using a compiler or an assembler?  what assembler are you using?

Comment: i am using NASM assembler, when i used MASM then it fails with error "asm open failed".

Comment: Nasm requires the segment to be inside the brackets: `lds si, [ss:bx]`

Comment: thanks prl,, my first error is solved.  please help me solving next error also.

Comment: A far immediate jump in NASM like here needs to be specified as `jmp 70h:0` -- no "far" keyword and using the "h" suffix for the hexadecimal number.